# C string comparison in program to report countries and capitals

Tags: c

I need to make a program where you give the countries and their capitals, then the user gives a country and the program gives back the capital of that country. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char country[3][20];
    char capital[3][20];
    int n=1, i, d, s;
    char p;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\nCountry: ");
        scanf(" %s", country[i]);
        printf("\nCapital: ");
        scanf(" %s", capital[i]);
    }
    while (n==1){
        printf("\nGive a country: ");
        scanf(" %s", p);
        i=0;
        while(i<3 && d!=i){
            if(strcmp(p,country[i])==0){
                d=i;
            }else{
                i++;
            }
        }
        printf("\nThe capital of %s is %s",country[d], capital[d]);
        printf("\nWant to search again? 1) yes    2)no ");
        scanf("%d", &s);
        if(s==2){
            n=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It's good that you've included an MCVE ([MCVE]) — thank you.  But you've not explained what problem(s) you're having that you need help to resolve.  Generally, it's best to end outputs with a newline rather than start them with a newline — prompts are an obvious exception.

Comment: Note that using `char p;` with `scanf(" %s", &p);` is a problem with undefined behaviour.  `%s` needs space for input characters and a null byte, and a single character like `p` doesn't provide enough space.  You probably want `%c` instead, and then the leading blank in the format is important.  For the `%s` inputs, the leading blank is not needed, though it doesn't cause any damage (trailing blanks would be a different story — they're a dire mistake in an interactive program and bad in non-interactive programs too).

Comment: d is also used uninitialized. Make sure to use -Wall (warn all) when you compile.